# Why does /tər/ (/ˈdɑːktər/ doctor or /ˈsɪstər/ sister) in American Accent sound like /trə/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I feel like `/tər/` (`/ˈdɑːktər/` doctor or `/ˈsɪstər/` sister) in American Accent sound like `/trə/`.

I couldn't find this info on the internet.

It seems that when we curl up the blade of the tongue too soon & that is why they sound like `/ˈdɑːktrə/` doctor or `/ˈsɪstrə/` sister.

Why does `/tər/` (`/ˈdɑːktər/` doctor or `/ˈsɪstər/` sister) in American Accent sound like `/trə/`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't. If it did, *spectre* (pronounced /ˈspɛk.təɹ/ and *spectra* (pronounced  /ˈspɛk.tɹə/) would be exact homophones, and they aren't, although they do sound similar.

Similarly, we don't think *Dexter* and *extra* are perfect rhymes, although you could get around this in a humorous poem by pronouncing *extra* as *exter*.

Maybe some aspect of your native language makes them sound the same to you.

We usually don't actually say /ˈspɛktər/. We usually use either a syllabic /r/ (/ɹ̩/ in IPA) or a r-colored schwa (/ɚ/ in IPA) for /ər/, so either way it's only one phone and not two. But *spectra* is indeed /ɹə/, and I don't usually have any trouble telling these two sounds apart.

Comment: Maybe your accent is different, listen to this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sister

Comment: Maybe your accent sounds like this http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sister?q=sister

Comment: In neither of these is the schwa pronounced *after* the /r/. The first one sounds to me like /ˈsɪstɚ/, where the /r/ and the /ə/ are combined into one sound (this is what I'm used to hearing), while the second sounds like /ˈsɪstər/ where the /ə/ is pronounced *before* the /r/. Try listening to [extra](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/extra) to hear the difference between /-tər/ and /-trə/.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you are expecting Americans to pronounce the /ə/ first and the /r/ second, and that's why you don't think *sister* sounds like /ˈsɪstər/. We don't usually do that; we combine the  /ə/ and the /r/ into one sound, often represented in IPA as  /ˈsɪstɚ/.

Comment: Why do [dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sister) represent *sister* as /ˈsɪstər/ rather than  /ˈsɪstɚ/, when that's the way most Americans pronounce it?  I don't know.

Comment: So, is **/t/** in  **/ˈsɪs.tɚ/** aspirated or not? According to the theory, if **/t/** followed by an **/s/** & if **/st/** cluster belongs to 1 morpheme then **/t/** will not be aspirated, but somehow they used a dot **/ˈsɪs.tɚ/**  between **/s/ & /t/** so I think they belong to 2 morphemes & therefore /t/ is aspirated a bit and somehow like /tʃ/.

Comment: the lip is more tense & more protruded & more closed when you pronounce **təɹ** in"spectre", but it is less tense & less protruded & less closed  when you pronounce **/tɹə/** in "spectra"

Comment: @Tom:  The /t/ in *sister* isn't like /tʃ/ ... *jester* and *gesture* are not pronounced the same, at least not by anybody I've hear speaking. That's because the /r/ in *sister* and *jester* is not pronounced before /ə/.